# Algebraic Combinations : Meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field and $K(u)$ be an algebraic extension of $K$. Now $u$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial over $K$. Does that mean  $u$ can be written as algebraic combinations of elements of $K$?

In the first place what does expressing something as algebraic combinations mean ? This question might be a trivial one but I am having some conceptual doubt regarding the meaning of algebraic combinations ! I would appreciate if the definition is elaborated and some remarks are made.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

In general, an "algebraic combination" of some objects is just a polynomial expression in these objects. So if $K$ is a field, an algebraic combination of elements of $K$ is also an element of $K$.

So no, $u$ cannot be written as such a combination unless $u\in K$.

Comment: Adding on to that. when we say $u$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial over $K$, we mean there exist $a_{n-1},\ldots,a_1,a_0 \in K$ such that
$$f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$$
cannot be factorized into polynomials of smaller degree with coefficients in $K$, and $f(u) = 0$.

Comment: do polynomial expressions include negative powers?

Comment: No, they do not, but on the other hand for any non-zero element of $x\in K(u)$, you can express $x^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $x$ (but this polynomial depends on $x$ itself), so depending on what you want to do it might still work.